# Java Equivalent for .NET Encryption-DESCryptoServiceProvider

Tags: java, .net, des, encryption-symmetric

Good Day, I need to encrypt some text using the base64 encoding and pass the encoded data to .NET application. The .NET application uses the following form of encoding & decoding. I have tried this [Equivalent to CryptoStream .NET in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4489942/equivalent-to-cryptostream-net-in-java).
I have used Apache commons codec for this purpose following the above link. But Stuck with the cryptoProvider.CreateEncryptor(bytes, bytes) , When i checked the third parameter in java equivalent -

> Cipher.init(cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE,key,iv)

it  must be an IvParameterSpec.I dont know how to solve this. Hope to get some help, Cheers!

> .NET encryption

```
static byte[] bytes = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes("mykey");
public static string Encrypt(string originalString)
{        
    DESCryptoServiceProvider cryptoProvider = new DESCryptoServiceProvider();
    MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
    CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream,cryptoProvider.CreateEncryptor(bytes, bytes), CryptoStreamMode.Write);
    StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(cryptoStream);
    writer.Write(originalString);
    writer.Flush();
    cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
    writer.Flush();
    return Convert.ToBase64String(memoryStream.GetBuffer(), 0, (int)memoryStream.Length);
}
```

Equivalent

> Java Encryption

```
void encrypt(String inputText) throws Exception {
    try {
        String myKey = "mykey";
        byte[] mybyte = str.getBytes("ASCII");
        //String plainIV = "1234567890ABCDEF";
        KeySpec keySpec = new DESKeySpec(myKey.getBytes("ASCII"));
        SecretKey key = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("DES").generateSecret(keySpec);
        //IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex.decodeHex(plainIV.toCharArray()));
        IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(mybyte);
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE,key,iv);
        byte[] encoded = cipher.doFinal(inputText.getBytes("ASCII"));   
        System.out.println("Encoded Value ..... "+Base64.encodeBase64(encoded));
    } catch(UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        System.out.println("Exception .. "+ e.getMessage());
    }
```

In .Net i get this- AOb0B20x2onFGz+JaFBsZyFbvCS9WF49D as the encoded value but in java, I'm getting wired encoded string- =�SKNv?�N�Ɛq{���U�;�/Z���8��<

Edit:-

Followed zacheusz and solved encoding problem, but encoded strings in both .NET and java are different...

Comment: and what error you get? your code looks fine (I didn't ran it). Could you provide real samples of key and IV?

Comment: @ zacheusz I have updated my question with the data

Comment: I think I found your bug. Assuming that you are using right string encoding (ASCII). I gues that it may be rather UTF8. Look at my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see that in .NET you are specyfing IV:

```
cryptoProvider.CreateEncryptor(bytes, bytes)
```

According to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0dh224hh.aspx) the second byte array is the IV. So you should use the same array in Java.

I think that the bug is here:

```
cipher.doFinal(Base64.encodeBase64(inputText.getBytes("ASCII")));
```

You are b64 encoding input before decrypting it.

Try

```
    byte[] output = cipher.doFinal(inputText.getBytes("ASCII"));  
    System.out.println("Encoded Value ..... "+new String(Base64.encodeBase64(output)));
```

Additional remarks (regarding your questions in comments):

- you need the same iv for Java and .NET
- the [constructor for IvParameterSpec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/crypto/spec/IvParameterSpec.html#IvParameterSpec%28byte%5B%5D%29) takes byte[] as an argument
- In .NET the [CreateEncryptor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0dh224hh.aspx) method takes byte[] IV as second argument:

Comment: that solved my encoding problem, but the encoded data in .Net & Java is different.(Ofcourse iv is diffrent in both). Is it possible to use the byte[] as the iv in java, just like that in .NET ?

Comment: (1.) you need the same iv for Java and .NET 

(2.) the constructor for IvParameterSpec takes byte[] as an argument http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/crypto/spec/IvParameterSpec.html#IvParameterSpec(byte[])

(3.) In .NET the CreateEncryptor method takes byte[] IV as second argument: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0dh224hh.aspx

Comment: thanks bro!!!, i have passed the byte[] to the IvParameterSpec but the same problem exists, i have updated my code

Comment: so you have to confirm few things: if you are using the same mode in .NET (CBC), the same padding (PKCS5Padding) and the same char encoding (ASCII)

Comment: from here <a>http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12894722/c-sharp-and-java-des-encryption-value-are-not-identical</a>, in .NET Default Properties of DES are, Mode : CBC and Padding : PKCS7 and also Character encoding is same in both ("ASCII").

Answer (score 2):

Thank you @zacheusz, 
I got it!!!
It was a silly mistake,I was printing the byte[] value, i forget to convert it to String

So Changed

> System.out.println("Encoded Value ..... "+Base64.encodeBase64(encoded));

To

> System.out.println("Encoded Value ..... "+new String(Base64.encodeBase64(encoded),"ASCII");

and That Solved my problem. Also modified code with [ByteArrayOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html).
Here is the Encoding & Decoding functions

```
String encrypt(String inputText) throws Exception {
    byte[] keyValue = new byte[] { 'm', 'y', 'k', 'e', 'y', 'n', 'u', 'l'};
    ByteArrayOutputStream bout = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try {           
        KeySpec keySpec = new DESKeySpec(keyValue);
        SecretKey key = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("DES").generateSecret(keySpec);
        IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(keyValue);
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES/CBC/PKCS5Padding"); 
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE,key,iv);
        bout.write(cipher.doFinal(inputText.getBytes("ASCII")));                        
    } catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception .. "+ e.getMessage());
    }
    return new String(Base64.encodeBase64(bout.toByteArray()),"ASCII");
}

String decrypt(String inputText) throws Exception {
    byte[] keyValue = new byte[] { 'm', 'y', 'k', 'e', 'y', 'n', 'u', 'l'};
    try {
        KeySpec keySpec = new DESKeySpec(keyValue);
        SecretKey key = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("DES").generateSecret(keySpec);
        IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(keyValue);

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE,key,iv);
        //byte[] decoded = Base64.decodeBase64(inputText); //Works with apache.commons.codec-1.8
        byte[] decoded = Base64.decodeBase64(inputText.getBytes("ASCII"));// works with apache.commons.codec-1.3
        bout.write(cipher.doFinal(decoded));
    } catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception ... "+e);
    }
    return new String(bout.toByteArray(),"ASCII");
}
```

Hope Someone will find it helpful...